# VisualWorks- Smalltallk Canvas View Error 108

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

When I try to install a New Canvas I get this error:
Error 108 Cannot make edition of TestThree in testAppStayBack because TestThree is not visible.

But the code is very visible as it can be found when I define it. This only happens when I try to open it.

Answer (score 3):

That's an Envy message, it's indicating that the application in which it's defining the class does not have the application that contains the class definition in its prerequisites. Chances are that the canvas editor is choosing the wrong application to install the canvas definition.

Comment: Hi Alan, can you tell me what would be the best possible fix for this error. As I am new to visualWorks and don't understand the enviorment  or layout fully  yet

Comment: Find where the class definition of TestThree is. It sounds like perhaps it ought to be in testAppStayBack. If so, and it's not, move it there. If it should be somewhere else, then add the location as a prerequisite of testAppStayBack.